# Handling multiple managedobjectcontext

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, managedobjectcontext

I have three managed object context, namely :

```
masterManagedObjectContext(NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType), 
backgroundMangedObjectContext(NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType), 
uiManagedObjectContext(NSMainQueueConcurrencyType)
```

Master is the parent, and other two are its children. When I save any child context, I do save master context. But when `backgroundMangedObjectContext` saves in master, `UIManagedObjectContext` did not get the updated data in `executeFetchRequest`.

How do I achieve this? Please help. I am very much caught into this issue for past three days.

There were some posts suggest that, I must invalidate the previously fetched objects, when master gets saved. But I have no clue how to do it.

I tried

`[UIManagedObjectContext reset]`

But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You need to add observer in viewDidLoad or init method,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextDidSave:)
name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
```

and implement this method,

Wherever you call this method [context save:nil], it will call automatically and changes will update to masterContext.

```
- (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    SEL selector = @selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:);
    [[self masterManagedObjectContext] performSelectorOnMainThread:selector withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];

}
```

Comment: actually masterManagedObjectContext is getting the updated changes. But my uiManagedObjectContext is not.

Comment: in which mangedObjectContext you want to update, use this in this code.[yourManageObjectContext performSelectorOnMainThread:]

Comment: I also read that, after iOS5 we don't need to do this mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification. When we use parent/child context, it will be automatically taken care of. Am I wrong?

Comment: if you use different contexts, you need to use this method. i'm also facing this issue in my project and i handled like this.